# Adding class to the itemView when model Added

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I use Backbone & Marionette for my webapp,

I Have a collection of tracks, when a track is added and when the player don't read any track, I want put "played" style to itemView, or "paused" to the track added on the cue.

So I want to add a class for each new Backbone model.

When I add a model, the class is added to the previous element, but not on the newest.
This is my CompositeView :

```
var trackListYTView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
template: "#playlist",
id: "trackList",
itemView: trackView,
itemViewContainer: "tbody",
initialize: function(){
     this.bindTo(this.collection, "add", this.modelAdded);
},
modelAdded: function(model){
     if(status) this.$('#status').addClass('icon-pause');
     else this.$('#status').addClass('icon-play');
}
```

I think "this" is not the good selector for the new itemView.

Thanks for helps, Luca

Comment: please provide more description of what you're trying to accomplish and why. there isn't enough here to understand the behavior and end result you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the selector - #status. **The element id should be unique**. You should not have multiple elements with same id. Use a class selector, for example '.statusClass', instead of '#status'.

Comment: This not work, I don't use the good "this" selector for the new itemView created.